# What is the minimum time required to catch all the apples on the line?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I am standing at point $0$ on line in one dimension. In the points $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ (some of the points might have negative coordinates) there are apples. I want to catch all of them. What is the minimum time required to do so?

Comment: How does time enter into this? I suppose you can move at unit speed in either direction along that line ...

Comment: Yes, I move at unit speed in any direction.

Comment: How many apples can you hold at a time? Do you have to go back every time you pick an apples?

Comment: There is no limit on how many apples I can have with me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $$\max_i x_i-\min_i(-x_i)+\min\{\max_i x_i,-\min_i x_i\}$$
if both positive and negative $x_i$ occur, and
$$\max_i|x_i|$$
otherwise.

In the first situation, you must run the full length form $\max$ to $\min$ in one direction or the other, depending on which of the two apples you catch first, and you must reach one of these two before that.
In the second situation, you must run from $0$ to the farthest out apple somehow. So both values cannot be beaten.